# MWFSlideNavigationViewController don't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, slideup

I'm  trying use MWFSlideNavigationViewController but it's not working.

When the button is tapped, should appear the hide ViewController but nothing happened

If I put 'self' in initWithRootViewController method, when I run the project, I just have a black screen on the ViewController. I'm calling this method in the Current ViewController.

```
MWFSlideNavigationViewController * slideNVC = [[MWFSlideNavigationViewController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self];
```